# Write Karate summary report output as a log/txt/csv instead of default html

Tags: karate

Is there a way we can write Karate summary report output as a log/txt/csv instead of default html. We wish to log the reports generated by cucumber features as log file instead of the default summary report html that is generated by Junit via Karate framework.

Comment: not supported, you can consider writing your own report or contribute